# Resolution of this system of equation

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I am currently on the verge of a nervous breakdown for an apparent easy-to-solve system of equations. I may miss something to get the key of the problem if the system is solvable but it should be.

Let $$A \in \mathbb{R^+}, B \in \mathbb{R^+}, t \in \mathbb{R^+}, 0 <\alpha  <90°$$  the variables to determine, which are related by the following system of equations :

\begin{cases} A \cos \alpha = B \cos \beta \quad (1) \\
A \sin \alpha = B \sin \beta +g t \quad (2) \\
A (t+D) \cos \alpha  = E- L_2 \sin \alpha - L_3 \cos \alpha \quad (3) \\
A (t+D) \sin \alpha  = \dfrac{gt^2}{2} + F - L_2 \cos \alpha -L_3 \sin \alpha \quad (4)
 \end{cases}

With :  $ -90 < \beta < 0°, D > 0, E > 0, F \in \mathbb{R^+}, L_2 > 0, L_3 > 0, g > 0 $,   known variables.

If you have the solution of this system with the demonstration, I would be so grateful !

Have a nice day !

Adrien

EDIT : Following @Claude's suggestion,

Giving : $s = \sin \alpha, \quad c = \cos \alpha$ :

From $(1)$, $B = \dfrac{Ac}{\cos\beta} \quad (5)$

$(2)$ and $(5)$ : $t  = \dfrac{A(s-c\tan\beta)}{g} \quad (6)$

Dividing $(4)$ by $(3)$ :

$\dfrac s c =\dfrac{\dfrac{A^2 (s-c \tan (\beta ))^2}{2 g}+F- L_2 c-L_3 s}{E-L_2 s-L_3 c}$

Leading to :

$A = \dfrac{\sqrt{ 2g( E\dfrac s c - L_2\dfrac{1-2c^2}{c}-F)}}{s-c\tan\beta} \quad (7) $

$(7)$ into $(6)$ :

$t = \sqrt{\dfrac{2(E\dfrac{s}{c}-L_2 \dfrac{1-2c^2}{c} - F)}{g}} \quad (8)$

Using $(7)$, $(8)$ into $(3)$ leads to :

$\sqrt{a_1c^3+b_1 c+d_1cs} \left( \sqrt{\dfrac{a_2 s^2 + b_2 s + d_2 c + e_2}{c}} + D\right) = a_3s^2+b_3c^2+d_3 cs + e_3 c + f_3 s  \quad (9)$

$a_i,b_i,d_i,e_i,f_i$ kwown variables.

I don't manage to solve this due to mix of square-root and non-square-root members...

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? Can you solve the problem for special choices of the known variables, e.g. $\beta = 0, \, g = 0$? And where does this system come from?

Comment: Hello Hans, I investigated many paths to find the solution : calculating $$(1)^2 + (2)^2$$ and $$(3)^2 +(4)^2$$, or trying to isolate variables, but I didn't succeed. $$g$$ is the gravity constant and $$\beta = -75°$$ an angle. Both can't be equal to 0.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment. It comes from classical mechanics.

Comment: Did you try to eliminate some of the variables as a function of others ?

Comment: Hello Claude, yes I tried this method like Gaussian elimination, but I didn't succeed. There is always 2 variables remaining including $\alpha$.

Comment: Could you write in the post what you have obtained ?

Comment: Look at my edit

Comment: Thank you Claude, but can you give me the tip to remove the $\sqrt{\dfrac{a_2 s^2 + b_2 s + d_2 c + e_2}{c}}$ term. 
I would have calculated the square of Eq. $(9)$, but it does not remove it

Answer (score 1):

I think that we can do a few things. First, let $\color{blue}{c=\cos(\alpha)}$ and $\color{blue}{s=\sin(\alpha)}$. So the equations are

$$ A c = B \cos (\beta) \tag 1$$
$$A s = B \sin (\beta) +g t \tag 2$$
$$A (t+D) c  = E- L_2 s - L_3 c \tag 3$$
$$A (t+D) s  = \dfrac{1}{2}gt^2 + F - L_2 c -L_3 s \tag 4$$

- Solve $(1)$ for $B$
- Plug $B$ in $(2)$ and solve for $t$
- Divide $(4)$ by $(3)$
  $$\frac s c =\frac{\frac{A^2 (s-c \tan (\beta ))^2}{2 g}+F- L_2 c-L_3 s}{E-L_2 s-L_3 c} \qquad \implies \qquad A= $$

Now, I shall write $(3)$ with in red everything we know
$$\color{red}{A (t+D)} c  = \color{red}{E- L_2} s - \color{red}{L_3} c  \tag 5$$

We then face a single equation is $s$ since  $c=\sqrt{1-s^2}$.

When $(5)$ is solved for $s$, you have $\alpha$ and go back  to have $A$, $t$ and $B$.

**Edit**

Assuming that your last line is correct, you face the problem of solving a polynomila equation of degree $\large 14$ in $s$.

Comment: I deeply apologize, there is a mistake in the system, eq. (2)... That's a $A \sin \alpha$ rather than $B \sin \alpha$... I will investigate a similar method you requested. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but I don't understand where Eq. (7) comes from, could you detail it more precisely ?

Comment: Thank you Claude for the update ! I still struggle to solve it. As $A = \sqrt{f(c,s)}$, $t = \sqrt{h(c,s)}$, Eq. (3) contains square root and non-square-root members of $\sin$ and $\cos$. I can't use square of Eq. (3) as it remains square root members included in $(t+D)$.
I hope my comment is clear enough.
Kind regards.

Comment: @Adrien. Didn't you write that $A \in R^+$ ?

Comment: Yes it is strictly positive. But I don't see how it solves the problem. I am sorry if it is related to basics but my mind is getting blurred with this problem.

Comment: @Adrien.Post a set of values in the question. Otherwise, it could become a no-end discussion.

Comment: I edited the post to make it more understandable...

Comment: @Adrien. I hope that you do not expect an explicit solution. At this point, everything will be done numerically.

Comment: You mean that there is no analytical solution ?

Comment: @Adrien. For sure !

Comment: Oh well I expected there was an analytical solution. Could I ask you how you can be sure that no analytical solution exists ?  My idea was there is 4 independent equations with 4 unkwown variables, so an analytical solution should exist.

Comment: @Hi Claude ! I just answered to a simplified version of this question that the asker has posted some hours ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388626/305862). Indeed, as here, I reach the same conclusion of an underdetermined system...