# Trigonometric system resolution with 4 variables

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have already posted a quite similar problem, which I simplify and I would like to know **if the system is solvable and if not, how to prove it**.

Let $A,B,t,\alpha$

4 unknown variables, with $A > 0, B > 0, t > 0, \alpha < 90°$

The system of 4 equations is the following :

\begin{cases} A \cos \alpha = B \cos \beta \quad (1) \\
A \sin \alpha = B \sin \beta +g t \quad (2) \\
A (t-D) \cos \alpha  = E-C \cos \alpha \quad (3) \\
A (t-D) \sin \alpha  = \dfrac{gt^2}{2} + F - C \sin \alpha \quad (4)
\end{cases}

With $C,D,E,F,g$ positives constants and $\beta = -75°$

I would like to express $A,B,t$ and $\alpha$ as a function of $C,D,E,F,g$ and $\beta$.

I unsuccesfully attempted several methods to solve it, with standard methods to solve a trigonometric system (using $\cos ^2 \alpha + \sin ^2 \alpha = 1$, and so on.

If $\alpha$ is fixed and $\beta$ the variable, the system is easily solvable using (3) et (4) :

$(3) \sin \alpha - (4) \cos \alpha$ gives :

$E \sin \alpha = \dfrac{gt^2}{2} \cos \alpha + F \cos \alpha$ leading to :

$t = \sqrt{2 (\dfrac{E \tan \alpha - F}{g})}$

$(3)$ gives :

$A = \dfrac{E-C \cos\alpha}{(t-D) \cos \alpha}$

$(1)^2  + (2)^2$ gives :

$B = \sqrt{A^2+(gt)^2-2Agt \sin \alpha}$

And eventually :

$\beta = \arccos({\dfrac{A \cos \alpha}{B}})$

Thanks for reading, and for your (hopefully) upcoming suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping equations (1) and (2), and grouping equations (3) and (4) under complex form, we get an **equivalent** system:

$$\begin{cases}Ae^{i \alpha}&=&Be^{i\beta}+igt & (eq. 1i)\\(A(t-D)+C)e^{i \alpha}&=&E+i(gt^2/2+F) & (eq. 1ii)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

In particular, in equation (1 ii), by identifying the moduli and the arguments of the LHS and RHS:

$$\begin{cases}(A(t-D)+C)^2&=&E^2+(gt^2/2+F)^2 & (eq. 2i)\\ \alpha &=& \arctan \frac{1}{E}(gt^2/2+F) & (eq. 2ii)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Eq. (2 i) allows to express $A$ as a function of $t$ and known quantities.

Using these informations together with (2 i) in (1 i), transformed into the form:

$$B=e^{-i\beta}(Ae^{i\alpha}-igt)\tag{3}$$

where the RHS of (3) is a function of the single variable $t$. It is in general a complex expression.
As the LHS is real, express that the imaginary part of the RHS is $0$ gives an equation in variable $t$, which should solve the problem !

Remark : of course, the real part of the RHS must be positive...

Comment: Thank you Jean for your quick answer. 

I understand your demonstration, but I don't think I can constrain $Be^{i\beta}$ in the context of my problem. I'll try to figure it out. 

I am still surprised that the problem is easily solvable for $\alpha$ known and $\beta$ unknown and not reciprocally.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the practical context of your issue. Robotics ?

Comment: "$B$ and $\beta$ can be expressed themselves as functions of $t$ and known quantities" I think that $\beta$ is fixed (known) since the question says "With $C,D,E,F,g$ positives constants and $\beta = -75°$" and "I would like to express $A,B,t$ and $\alpha$ as a function of $C,D,E,F,g$ and $\beta$". Also, I think that (eq. 1i) should be $Ae^{i \alpha}=Be^{i\beta}+\color{red}igt$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Indeed, it is a robotics problem. I may have found a missing equation which could solve the system. mathlove Yes, $\alpha$ is the variable and $\beta$ is kwown, but Eq. (3) still remains with 2 variables ($B$ and $t$). Thanks to both of you for your comments.

Comment: @mathlove You are perfectly right. Thank you. I am going to fix the errors.

Comment: Now, the problem has a solution ! Thank you again to @mathlove !

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie. By taking another look to my problem, I found a supplementary equation. But after analysis, this equation was equivalent to an other. Im on the way to try your suggestion, I inform you ASAP if it solves my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice approach and answer

Comment: It works ! Thanks @JeanMarie

Answer (score 0):

Following @Jean Marie approach :

The imaginary part of equation (3) leads to :

\begin{equation}
\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{E^2+(g\dfrac{t^2}{2}+F)^2}-C}{t-D} \right) \left(\dfrac{(g\dfrac{t^2}{2}+F) \sin \beta + E \cos \beta}{\sqrt{E^2+(gt^2/2+F)^2}} \right)- gt \cos\beta = 0
\end{equation}

This equation contains only the variable $t$ but I don't know how to get rid of the square of the left member. I can't calculate the square of the equation $(3)^2$  as a square member still remains.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Edit : it may be only solvable by numerical optimization ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes it is to be solved by a numerical method. It is rare, in practical applications to have explicit formulas.